# What happens when a file being downloaded is modified on the server?

Tags: java, network-programming, download, network-protocols

I'm downloading a zip file from a server but keep getting corrupted file.  I have a slow connection and I know that the server keeps updating the file frequently.  Is this why I get corrupted files?  I would assume the network protocol should be smart enough to avoid this kind of situations.

```
private void downloadFile(String urlString, String fileName)
        throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    InputStream input = new URL(urlString).openConnection().getInputStream();
    FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
    int bufferSize = 153600;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    int totalBytesRead = 0;
    int bytesRead = 0;

    while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
    }

    output.close();
    input.close();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The network protocol has nothing to do with the data sent through it.  That's up to the server implementation.

Comment: This has nothing to do with A "network protocol". And I doubt the server is *modifying* a `.zip` file instead of just creating a new one with the same name (which wouldn't affect a currently open filehandle). If the latter is incorrect ... yeah, well, don't do that.

Comment: The `new byte[]` in the loop should be removed. You could use a proven library like `org.apache.commons.io.StreamUtils.pipe(input, output)`.

Comment: @JoopEggen, Thanks. I'll have a look.

Comment: @BrianRoach, could you be more specific?  I guess the server is creating new files instead of modifying them.  If so, what would be the cause of the corrupted files? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's nothing to do with the protocol, and everything to do with the server software you're using at the other end of your URL. Your code can only read what the server sends you. The *server* code needs to ensure that it either maintains a write lock on the file while it's streaming it out to you, or otherwise ensures you receive a valid copy of the (unmodified) file.

Comment: Then it's the server's problem. I feel better now. :)